# symplectic gromov witten invariants of weighted projective space

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, gromov-witten-theory, pseudo-holomorphic-curves

Does anyone know if the symplectic (genus zero) GW invariants have been computed for weighted projective spaces? It seems there are already algebraic computations https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608481
Is orbifold symplectic GW theory a well established theory or a work in progress?